# Is $X$ homeomorphic to $S^1 \times Y$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is it true that when the first fundamental group of a topological space $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ then $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times Y$ where  the first fundamental group of $Y$ is trivial?

With a discussion with my of friends, the above question turned into (!) finding a topological space $X$ s.t. there is no quotient space obtained from $X$ being homeomorphic to $S^1.$

Comment: A little modification!

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on http://math.stackexchange.com as the counterexample is well-known to students of topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M"obius band is a counterexample (to the original and current versions of the stated question).

Comment: Yes, it's been edited sir. I'm new to this field. Can you elaborate it more, please?  